# How to get column index a td in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table, where I select some rows then move column values (from an `<input>` control) to another column (also an `<input>` control). The catch here is, the columns are `pre-selected (from data input)` and the columns can be dynamically arranged (with id's)

I can move the values but at the moment, I have the columns hard coded. It has to be from the data input.

```
Input: ColB, ColD

colA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE

10      20      30      40      50
30      40      50      60      70
50      60      70      80      90
70      80      90      100     110
```

Will require to add/append **`ColB`** values **`ColD`**

Here's a snippet:

```
var cols = $(row).find("td");
var a = parseInt($(cols[x]).find("input").val(), 10);
```

Where: `x` is the index of a column which may be dynamic and I'll have to search for it using column id's.

Comment: sorry, the requirement is not clear.. can you share the html and explain it again

Comment: please show the html and how you are selecting column ? i mean on click or checkbox ?

Comment: @Panther: the columns are selected from a drop-down list, so it can be from ColA...E for the first input, same from second input.  <br/>  

the snippets above are my means of getting the value from the selected column.  <br/>  

    `code` var a = parseInt($(cols[x]).find("input").val(), 10);  <br/>  
    `code` var b = parseInt($(cols[y]).find("input").val(), 10);  <br/>  

the x and y are supposed to be the column id of the selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So it seems that you're looking to get the values from all the `<input>` elements in a given column, given a column ID. You get the column id from the ddl, and then you want an array of values from that column.

So a function would do the trick here. Here you can call `getColumnValues()` with the column id from the ddl, and it'll return an array of values from that column:

```
function getColumnValues(columnId) {
    var colAIndex = $("#" + columnId).index();

    var vals = []
    $("td:eq(" + colAIndex + ")").each(function() {
        vals.push($(this).val());
    }
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: `code` var colAIndex = $("#colAId").index();  <br/>

this is close... but how do I make the 'colAId' a dynamic one? not hardcoded... thanks

Comment: Sure! Where does the dynamic value come from? Is it the id of the column header td?

Comment: it'll come from a ddl's selected value. the ddl contains a list of id's corresponding to the table's column header td.